# Como retornar dia de hoje input type date?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estou tentando preencher um campo input com `type="date"` com o data do dia que está sendo preenchido o formulário.

Tentei o seguinte código em PHP:

```
function getDatetimeNow() {
    $tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Brazil/East');
    $datetime = new DateTime();
    $datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
    return $datetime->format('Y-m-d ');
}
```

No HTML fiz o seguinte:

```
<input name="name_01" id="id_01" type="date" value="<?php echo getDatetimeNow() ?>" />
```

Não imprimiu nada, mas tentei também por JavaScript:

```
now = new Date; 
yr = now.getFullYear();
mt = now.getMonth();
dy = now.getDay();  
document.getElementById('id_01').innerHTML= yr+"-"+mt+"-"+dy;
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia, de como trazer o campo preenchido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com php, pode fazer assim:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
...
<input name="name_01" id="id_01" type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/yRhP3K)

Com javascript:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dy = today.getDate();
var mt = today.getMonth()+1;
var yr = today.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('id_01').value= yr+"-"+mt+"-"+dy;
```

```html
<input name="name_01" id="id_01" type="text" />
```